# How does Wordpress remember which editor is being used?

Tags: tinymce, post-editor, cookies

Hey so I am trying to determine how Wordpress remembers which editor is being used for a particular post (HTML or Visual Editor (tinyMCE)). When you write a post, and then come back, it goes to the last used editor. I am assuming its a cookie of some sort (because I couldn't find any info in the database), but does anyone know where the code for this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**wp-settings cookie screenshot**](http://i.minus.com/iQ4BioKuPK6GC.png)

its stored in the cookie wp-settings-USERID, replace USERID with the id of the logged in user.

the two values are editor=tinymce or editor=html

Comment: I was curious about this myself, thank you Ijaas :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but here's how I'd find out:

1. Install [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/) and find the name of the cookie.
2. Do a search for that cookie name in the WP codebase, using any number of text-search tools: grep, ack-grep, your IDE's search function etc.